What is the flux associated with the flat surface of a uniformly charged hemispherical shell?
Let us assume a uniformly charged hemispherical shell with net charge $Q$ uniformly distributed over the curved surface of the shell.
Now charge density $= σ = Q/2πR^2$
Now I wish to find out the flux associated with the flat surface of the shell.
Initially, I thought that the inner surface of the shell would have charge $σ*2πR^2$ and that would give us the answer. However, I later realised that the plane surface only has an area of $πR^2$ and was confused if even all of the electric field lines associated with the charge would go through the plane surface.
Furthermore, I recently learnt how a hemispherical shell was not a symmetrical object for Gauss law which further confused me about the methodology I used.
Please help me understand the net flux associated with the flat surface and whether it is associated with the complete $σ*2πR^2$ or not and if it isn't then what happens to the electric field lines that do not pass through the flat surface.

Your question does not make sense until you specify the surface through which you want to compute the flux.  Do you want to compute the flux through a sphere of radius $2R$ concentric with your hemisphere?  Do you want to compute the flux through a cube completely contained within the hemisphere?

I'm sorry for the inadequate explanation. I wanted to get the flux through the plane surface confident with the planar face of the hemisphere as I had thought that would be sufficient. I thought the sphere would not be possible as Gauss law wouldn't apply due to the asymmetric of the field due to the hemishpere.

Can we use a cube of side $2R$ inscribing the hemispherical shell and find the flux through the face of the cube parallel and confident with the plane surface of the hemispherical shell?
